# my result is 1st row: 2 group 2 file1 10 and 2nd row: 2 group 2 file2 10 in table but i want to show 2 group 2 file1 10 file2 10

Tags: sql

I am fetching file names for certain user and group name. I
 want filename which are in different rows to be in same row.

My result is:

```
2 group 2 file1 10    
2 group 2 file2 10
```

I want is:

```
2 group 2 file1 10 file2 10
```

My procedure:

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[DisplayDetails] 
        @User_Id int,
        @Group_Id int OUTPUT,
        @Group_Name varchar(255) OUTPUT,
        @No_of_flat_files int OUTPUT,
        @Filename varchar(255) OUTPUT,
        @No_of_records int OUTPUT


    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        select @Group_Id=Group_Id,
        @Group_Name=Group_Name,
        @No_of_flat_files=No_of_flat_files,@Filename=file_name,
        @No_of_records=No_of_records from INPUT_FILES_updated
        where file_sequence='1' and [User_Id]=@User_Id
        union 
        select @Group_Id=Group_Id,
        @Group_Name=Group_Name,
        @No_of_flat_files=No_of_flat_files,@Filename=file_name, 
        @No_of_records=No_of_records from INPUT_FILES_updated
        where file_sequence='2' and  [User_Id]=@User_Id
        union
         select @Group_Id=Group_Id,
        @Group_Name=Group_Name,
        @No_of_flat_files=No_of_flat_files,@Filename=file_name,
        @No_of_records=No_of_records from INPUT_FILES_updated
        where file_sequence='3' and  [User_Id]=@User_Id
        union
        select @Group_Id=Group_Id,
        @Group_Name=Group_Name,
        @No_of_flat_files=No_of_flat_files,@Filename=file_name,
        @No_of_records=No_of_records from INPUT_FILES_updated
        where file_sequence='4' and  [User_Id]=@User_Id



       RETURN  
    END





         Declare @Group_I int  ,@Group_Na varchar(50),@No_of_flat_fil int,
    @Filena varchar(255) ,  @No_of_reco int     

            Execute [dbo].[DisplayDetails] @User_Id=2, @Group_Id=@Group_I output,  @Group_Name=@Group_Na output,@No_of_flat_files=@No_of_flat_fil out,@Filename=@Filena out,@No_of_records=@No_of_reco

            SELECT @Group_I,@Group_Na ,@No_of_flat_fil, @Filena, @No_of_reco
```

Comment: And if there are 3 rows?

Comment: okay in this case we will take 3 files max and for last 4th file which is not available will be "-"  like    "  2 group 2 file1 10 file2 10 file3 10 - -"

Comment: do you have 1 row for each file_sequence? I mean,  file1 is from file_sequence1, file2 is from file_sequence2 and so on, or file1 and file2 could be both from file_sequence2 and no rows from file_sequence1?

Comment: file1 is from file_sequence1 ,file2 is from file_sequence2,so on

Comment: anybody could help